# ゲームのスコアを n 点獲得する毎に処理を実行するには？

Tags: c#, unity3d

敵を倒すゲームを作成中です、敵を倒してスコアを取得しスコアを20点獲得する毎に敵のスポーン値を上昇させる機能を作りたいのですが、スコアを20点獲得する毎に処理を動かす部分がわかりません、教えてください。

Comment: 例えば「敵を倒した」や「スコアを獲得した」などの判定については理解できているのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

スポーン管理するSpawnerオブジェクト
残機・スコア・ポーズ制御フラグetc.をまとめたGameSystemオブジェクト
があると仮定します

SpawnerがGameSystemオブジェクトを参照していれば良いのです。
スコアによってSpawnerの挙動が変わるコードはSpawner自身が持つべき挙動なので、
Spawner.Moveロジック（直接使っているならMonoBehaviour.Update）で
GameSystem.Scoreをチェックして、条件を満たしたらスポーン制御パラメータを変更します。

Answer (score 0):

方法1： １点ずつ加点する場合は割り算の余りを使う方法があります。

```cs
int score;

void AddScore()
{
  int n = 20;

  score++;
  if (score % n == 0)
  {
    AddSpawnRate();
  }
}
```

方法2： 加点が変化する場合は判定用の変数を導入します。

```cs
int score;
int bucket;

void AddScore(int value)
{
  int n = 20;

  score += value;
  bucket += value;
  while (bucket >= n)
  {
    bucket -= n;
    AddSpawnRate();
  }
}
```